# Neo4j show nodes which are directly related from list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to query my neo4 graph database for a list of nodes names and only show the nodes which are directly connected to each other. Additionally, if a node in the list does not have any related nodes, I would like the relation returned as null.

So for example if have node A related to B, C, D and a standalone node E.

I have currently got this:

```
MATCH (a:Node)
WHERE a.name IN ['A', 'B', 'E'] 
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:LINKED_TO]->(b:Node)
RETURN a, r, b
```

But this returns the additional nodes C, D which node A is related. What do I need to change to only bring back the nodes in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
WITH ['A', 'B', 'E'] as names
MATCH (a:Node)
WHERE a.name IN names
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r:LINKED_TO]->(b:Node)
WHERE b.name IN names
RETURN a, r, b
```